# How to update Knockout.js view model with server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have Knockout.js view model that has nested observable arrays.

```
   function ParentVM(data) {
        var self = this;

        self.childs= ko.observableArray([]);
        ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping, this);
    }

    function ChildVM(data) {
        var self = this;

        self.propertyA = ko.observableArray([]);
        self.propertyB = ko.observable();

        ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping, this);
    }

    function GrandChildVM(data) {
        var self = this;

        self.propertyX = ko.observable();
        self.propertyY = ko.observable();
        self.propertyZ = ko.observable();

        ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping, this);
    }
```

I have following bindings:

```
 data-bind="value: propertyX, valueUpdate: 'keydown'"
```

Now, how can I add event handler to call my REST endpoint to update view model state when these properties changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this is what you can do:

```
function ChildVM(data) {
    var self = this;

    self.propertyA = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.propertyB = ko.observable();

    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping, this);

    self.propertyA.subscribe(function (newValue) { /* call you're api with new value! */ });
    self.propertyB.subscribe(function (newValue) { /* call you're api with new value! */ });
}
```

Comment: Yes, but this does not seem to work. The subscribed callback does not get called.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense, is the model bound correctly? Do any values in the parameters get shown in the UI?

Comment: Thanks, the problem was that when the data was initialized it did not use the provided mapping. Changing ko.mapping.fromJS(data) to  ko.mapping.from(data, mapping) fixed the issue and subscribing to properties works.

Comment: Please make sure to mark me answer as the correct one, if it solved your problem. :)